# JSON Format - Forced Array

Tags: java, json

I am trying to format json, few objects need to be converted into an array.
json field is coming in three different ways:-

1. Working perfectly.

```
"Deliverytypes": {
        "DeliveryType": [
            "REST",
            "WORKSHOP"
        ]
    }
```

2. `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["DeliveryType"] is not a JSONArray.`

```
"Deliverytypes": {
        "DeliveryType": "REST"
    }
```

3. `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["Deliverytypes"] is not a JSONObject.`

```
"Deliverytypes": ""
```

1. is working perfectly but  2. & 3. are throwing above mentioned error.

My code is like below:

```
       if (json.has("Deliverytypes")) {
            unwrapDeliveryType(json);
        }
        
       private static void unwrapDeliveryType(JSONObject obj) throws 
        JSONException {
     JSONArray deliveryTypes = 
            obj.getJSONObject("Deliverytypes").getJSONArray("DeliveryType");
            obj.put("Deliverytypes", deliveryTypes);
      }
```

Comment: I think you need to add a custom deserialiser.

Comment: Could you please elaborate.

Comment: I think you need to add a custom deserialiser.
you may do this by adding annotation to the model class like `@JsonAdapter(TheClass.class)`, with the appropriate class of course, which needs to implement `JsonDeserializer<TheClass>`

Comment: FWIW, while you may have to deal with these incoming results from some other service, its behavior is hostile to its users precisely because it doesn't have a consistent data shape. Don't ever do this yourself, and yell at anyone you see doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `instanceof`

Like this

```java
Object types = obj.get("Deliverytypes");
if(types instanceof String) {
    // type 3, do what you need to do
} else if (types instanceof JSONObject) {
    JSONObject deliveryTypes = (JSONObject) types;
    Object type = deliveryTypes.get("DeliveryType");
    if(type instanceof String) {
        // Type 2
    } else if (type instanceof JSONArray) {
        JSONArray dTypes = (JSONArray) type;
        // Type 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model class, you can add an annotation like:

```
  @JsonAdapter(ModelDeserialiser.class)
  private Model model;
```

where the `ModelDeserialiser` class is the bespoke deserialiser for the class (i.e. it can deserialise the class into the different formats you require).

The `ModelSerialiser` class would then need to implement the `JsonDeserializer<T>` interface, where `T` is the class or superclass (I think?) of objects you intend to output (Could be `Object`). Within the bespoke deserialiser you would use `com.google.gson` API.